# Magento 2 Rewrite Category to CMS Page?

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite, cms-pages, catalog-url-rewrite

How can I redirect a category page to CMS Page using url rewrite system in magento 2.

Comment: Why you want to redirect category page to cms page?

Comment: actually I have static page in between main menu.So we can render static link at end of the dynamic menu links.But the tester need that static page link in the same order as mock up.So I created that static link also a category and arranged the order as per.Now I need to redirect that category to static  (cms) page.

Comment: This one for you @shankarboss. I have used this & it works fine. It redirect your category to CMS Page https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect

Comment: Hi @Ankit Shah, Can we not achieve category to cms page redirection by using Magento 2 default url rewrite system ?

Comment: Nope i tried that. It will cause Save issue for Category. So it's better to not do that. This is FREE plugin u can achieve ur requirement.

Comment: ok, but if we use more modules it may affect the store performance issue.